# How to use pre-trained model in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Like Caffe, there are also some pre-trained TensorFlow models on the Internet. However, unlike Caffe, whose models are always accompanied with a `.prototxt` file indicating the net structures and layer names, TensorFlow relies on Python code to define the neural networks. Meanwhile, for a variable in TensorFlow, its name may be very long due to the existence of `variable_scope`. This makes it very difficult to find a specific variable by the name. So, if I have downloaded a pre-trained TensorFlow model from the Internet without the network structure python code, how can I use it for my own project?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow models can be saved in protobuf format. This format very useful for storing trained models, graph saved with weights as constants, not variables. You can load it and initialize your own models by this data and finetune it.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphDef